# Static Map image not displaying

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to display a location point in map using static map API.  This above [link](http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?markers=color%3agreen%7C12.768946,79.973259&zoom=10&scale=2&size=200x100&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyBDf0cMjcnjCrmNP_pov0Yac1u4kOWPElI) contains the image and I am trying to show this image in an `ImageView`.
It throws `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. So I added these two lines

```
  StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = 
                     new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                    .permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

and now it works fine. But I want to know why NetworkOnMainThreadException.

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: if you remove those lines you get NetworkOnMainThread Exception. If you try to google for this exception you will get tons of links explaining "why" and how to fix it

Comment: did you try to look for NetworkOnMainThreadException?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use thread or asynctask if you will do network related operations. 
Check the most voted question about **NetworkOnMainThreadException** from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)